# Twelve Fold Way Method of Counting

Tags: combinatorics

25 students audition for 10 parts in a play. How many possible casts?

From having done multiple counting problems of this sort, I understand that the solution to this problem is 25!/(25-10)!.

For anyone that is familiar with the twelvefold way: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way

What should be identified as the balls (students or parts), and what should be the boxes (students or parts), and why? What is the intuitive reasoning for the assignment of balls and boxes?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In the notation used in the *The Twelvefold Way*, $N$ is the set of balls, here the $10$ different parts. The set $X$ of boxes is the $25$ students. We are counting the number of injective functions from $N$ to $X$.  For every part has to be assigned to a student, with distinct parts assigned to distinct students, hence the injectivity condition.

Comment: How do you know to assign the parts as balls and students as boxes? This is where I get confused.

Comment: If we try to have the students as the set of balls, with the parts as boxes, we would need to consider bijections from a **subset** of the set of balls onto the set of boxes. Counting these is not part of the *Twelvefold Way* classification.

Comment: so in order to use the Twelvefold Way, if only one ball can go into one box, the number of balls must be less than or equal to the number of boxes, correct?

Comment: I have checked the Wikipedia article. Your permutation problem is the first one listed in the discussion of classical combinatorial problems.

Comment: Certainly the set of balls can be bigger than the set of boxes *in general*, but if the functions have to be injective, then $X$ must be no smaller than $N$.